# TSConfig 'strict: false' leads to an error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
import { of, tap, ignoreElements } from 'rxjs';
export class C {
  private bar: number[] = [];
  public foo() {
    return of([1]).pipe(
      tap((x) => (this.bar = x)),
      ignoreElements()
    );
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&alwaysStrict=false&ts=4.9.4&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhAZgGjjAhmDwDmAdtAKYCiANiSCYTAM5wC+cKUEIcA5FAB4BW9LgG4AUKJK9IsOAGMKWeowDCiUXDhgowAG5YYJOACMsUAFxxCAVxBGSUANoBdOAF44zsRrBWjFYLKsEBAAFACUahoaUCQwVlCEyCghDgCMTmEAdGDAYCQh6lEa2GAhIbwRrgB8cCEwABbA9JkmUG5wFWFohUUExDGU1LQM4T1wYV7MokxAA)

The code is fine until you turn off 'strict' mode (to be precise 'strictFunctionTypes').
Uncheck 'strictFunctionTypes' and get errors in line `this.bar = x`:
`Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.`
`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

I discovered several ways to remove the errors in 'strict=false' mode:

1. set explicitly type of arrow function argument x `(x: number[]) => ...`
2. add another 'empty' `tap()` just before `ignoreElements()`
3. remove `ignoreElements()`

It seems `pipe()` signature resolves differently with strict mode on/off.
It's `pipe<number[], never>(...)` when `strict=true`
It's `pipe<unknown, never>(...)` when `strict=false`
I guess one of the reasons is `ignoreElements(): OperatorFunction<unknown, never>` signature with non-generic 'unknown'.

So I get error-free code with `strict=true` but it fails with `strict=false`.
Is this TS behavior intended?
What is the recommended solution?

Comment: Mind providing the version of typescript you’re using and the tsconfig? The package json would also be helpful.

Comment: Everything is available at the provided 'Playground link'.
I tried TS 4.9.4 and 4.8.4. TSConfig is available on 'TS Config' tab.
One can export the snippet to StackBlitz (for example) and get JSON files for the project.